# Using a Future integer in a class Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

If you were to use a Future and have a integer in it. Then how do you use it in a class? I have tried something, but I can't find a way to do it. Here's some code. **Btw the integer has to be in a Future.** Thanks in advance.

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Test createState() => _Test();
}

class _Test extends State<Test> {
  Future testFuture() async {
    final int _test = 10;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('$_test'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `FutureBuilder`

```dart
class _Test extends State<Test> {
  Future<int> testFuture() async {
    return 10;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<int>(
            future: testFuture(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
              String text;
              if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
                text = 'Is loading...';
              } else {
                text = '${snapshot.data}';
              }
              return Text(text);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I see the problem now. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to accept the answer for the future readers